# Is it possible to create a PostgreSQL index with json Include Columns?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-11

I am using PostgreSQL 11.8

```
CREATE INDEX ix_products_product_sku_with_json_columns
ON products USING btree((product_sku))
INCLUDE ((data->>'variantCode'));
```

> ERROR:  expressions are not supported in included columns
> SQL state: 0A000

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createindex.html) says:

> Expressions are not supported as included columns since they cannot be used in index-only scans.

I suppose `data->>'variantCode'` is an expression and that's the end of the story?
I can see two workarounds, none of which looks appealing to me:

- create a dedicated VariantCode regular SQL column in the table
- put `data->>'variantCode'` as part of the index keys

How bad is the second option?
Ultimately the goal would be to do an [Index-Only Scan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/indexes-index-only-scans.html) in the following query:

```
SELECT data->>'variantCode', ARRAY_AGG(product_sku)
FROM products
GROUP BY data->>'variantCode'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot have `data->>'variantCode'` as `INCLUDE` column, but also adding it as index key won't help you to get an index-only scan. PostgreSQL doesn't consider index keys that are not columns for an index-only scan. There is no fundamental problem that prevents that, it is just not implemented.

You'd have to add the whole `data` to the index, but that is not possible, since there is no B-tree operator class for `jsonb`.

So the only remaining option to get an index-only scan would be a generated column:

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD data_varcode text
   GENERATED ALWAYS AS (data->>'variantCode') STORED;
```

Then you can use that column in your query and index.

Comment: Indeed, I couldn't achieve Index-Only Scans using that json column in the index keys, only Bitmap Heap Scan.
Unfortunately I am running PostgreSQL 11.8 which doesn't include Generated Columns, but I can still create a regular column. Thanks